# Automatically attach source files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to configure that Eclipse IDE so that it automatically downloads and displays source code for dependency classes that are used? I tried using CTRL+click on the text `java.lang.annotation.retention`, but the source of `java.lang.annotation.retention` wasn't automatically downloaded and displayed when I navigated to it. Instead, I got the usual "source not found" error message. I want to know if it's possible to configure Eclipse so that it automatically attaches the source for `java.lang` classes (and perhaps other classes as well), so that the source won't need to be manually attached.

Comment: use JDK as default Installed JRE of Workspace.

Comment: @Imran What specific steps should I follow in order to do this?

Comment: In eclipse Select (Menu) Window> Prefrences> Java> Installed JREs